Spring Security Always Throws InsufficientAuthenticationException even when the SecuirtyContext is authetnicated
so i have been trying to make a jwt filter that "authenticates" the request.
JWTFilter.java:
`@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class JWTFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

private final JWTService jwtService;
private final UserDetailsService userService;

private Optional<String> getTokenFromHeader(HttpServletRequest request){
    final String authHeader = request.getHeader("Authorization");
    if(authHeader == null || !authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")){
        return Optional.empty();
    }
    return Optional.of(authHeader.substring(7));
}

@Override
protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
   FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {
    log.error("Running filter...");

    Optional<String> rawToken = getTokenFromHeader(request);

    if(rawToken.isEmpty()){
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        return;
    }

    // TODO handle all the exception
    try {
        String token = rawToken.get();

        // Validate
        jwtService.validateToken(token);

        /*
        if(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() != null){
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }*/

        String username = jwtService.getUserId(token);
        log.info("\n\nUsername " + username);

        UserDetails userDetails = userService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        log.info("\n\nuserdetails " + userDetails.toString());

        if(userDetails.getUsername() == null){
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, null, userDetails.getAuthorities());
        authenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);

        log.error("Doing last full auth is good " + SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated());
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

        log.error("AFTER DO FILTER CHECK  " + SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated());

    } catch (JwtException e) {
        response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED);
        response.getWriter().write("Invalid token " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
    }
}

}

`
and even tho by the logs is seems that the security context authentication is set to true, it still does not send the request to the controller!!
this is my security chain and the whole security configuration:
\`@Configuration
 @EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class SecurityConfig {

private final AuthorizationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;
private final JWTService jwtService;
private final UserRepository userRepository;
private final UserDetailsService userService;

@Bean
public SecurityFilterChain provideSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http.csrf(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);
    http.cors(AbstractHttpConfigurer::disable);

    http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) ->
        requests
            .requestMatchers("/auth/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/swagger-ui/**").permitAll()
            .requestMatchers("/v3/**").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
    )
    .authenticationManager(provideAuthManager(http));

    http.sessionManagement(sessionManagementConfigurer ->
        sessionManagementConfigurer.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
    );

    http.authenticationProvider(provideAuthenticationProvider());
    http.addFilterBefore(new JWTFilter(jwtService, userService), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    http.exceptionHandling(exception -> exception.authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler));

    return http.build();
}

@Bean
public PasswordEncoder provideEncoder(){
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationProvider provideAuthenticationProvider(){
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authProvider.setUserDetailsService(userService);
    authProvider.setPasswordEncoder(provideEncoder());
    return authProvider;
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager provideAuthManager(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder = httpSecurity.getSharedObject(AuthenticationManagerBuilder.class);
    authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userService).passwordEncoder(provideEncoder());
    return authenticationManagerBuilder.build();
}

}

`
this is the controller and the endpoint is the "post" endpoint that i am trying to reach:
\`@RestController()
@RequestMapping("/blog_posts")
@Slf4j
public class PostController {

private final PostsService postsService;

public PostController(PostsService postsService){
    this.postsService = postsService;
}

@GetMapping("/info")
public String getPosts(){
    return "Blog posts";
}

@GetMapping("/")
public List<BlogPost> getBlogPosts(@RequestParam() Long limit, @RequestParam Long offset){
    return postsService.getBlogPosts(limit, offset);
}

@PostMapping("/")
public BlogPost addBlogPost(@RequestParam AddBlogPostRequest request){
    log.error("Doing controller");

    Authentication authentication  = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    User user = (User) authentication.getDetails();

    BlogPost post = new BlogPost();
    post.setTitle(request.getTitle());
    post.setBody(request.getBody());
    post.setUserId(user.getId());

    return postsService.addBlogPost(post);
}

}

`
this is the bean and configuration for the userdetails service:
\`@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AppConfig {

private final UserRepository userRepository;

@Bean
public UserDetailsService provideUserDetailsService() throws Exception {
    return new UserDetailsService() {
        @Override
        public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            return userRepository.findByUsername(username)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found"));
        }
    };
}

}

`
please help me have been struggling with this for a three days,I have read all the forums tortured chatgpt and cannot find a solution. I have also asked my friends looked at multiple video tutorials i just dont know what to do.

I don't see any logs where it says your context is authenticated.

log.error("Doing last full auth is good " + SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated());
filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    log.error("AFTER DO FILTER CHECK  " + SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().isAuthenticated());


I meant your log, not logging statements.
